Invertibility of a Vandermonde-like matrix
Let $A\subseteq \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$ be a finite set containing $n$ elements, will the $n\times n$ matrix $(i^kj^l)_{(i,j), (k,l)\in A}$ always be invertible? Here we take the convention $0^0=1.$
Let  me take an example to illustrate the matrix: if $A=\left\{(0,1), (3,3), (2,6)\right\}$, then the $3\times 3$ matrix should be
$$\begin{pmatrix}0^01^1 & 0^31^3 & 0^21^6
\\
3^03^1 & 3^33^3 & 3^23^6
\\
2^06^1 & 2^36^3 & 2^26^6\end{pmatrix}$$
I think this may be an variant of the Vandermonde matrix, but I can't not find a similar one. Any help?

If $A=\{(1,1),(-1,-1)\}$, then the $2\times 2$ matrix is $\begin{pmatrix} 1&1\\-1&-1\end{pmatrix}$, which is clearly not invertible.
